# Is a question on databases to hold medical records for clinical trials in the United States on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have run into an issue related to material that would have been pertinent/on-topic on the ill-fated Healthcare IT, but I'm not 100% positive it would be on-topic here.

I have a question regarding the specific requirements for hardening databases that will be used in clinical trials in the United States, both for federal requirements and for the privacy of those participating.

I'm sure that different countries may have different standards for maintaining such data, but I trust that aspect of it alone won't render it "too localized".

Would such a question be on-topic on Security.SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, but before you do, have a look at our existing questions on HIPAA as you may find what you need:https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=hipaa

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten you guys had a HIPAA tag.  I was a mod on the ill-fated Healthcare IT, so I should have known.  Still, I have some lingering doubts as to whether the clinical trials data must be held under the same (or even more stringent) standards.  I'm less sure if that aspect is on-topic.

Comment: We do have a challenge with regs that are country specific, buy we seem to be coping okay so far - laws are a different matter, as legal advice is off topic, but industry regs are generally fine. And the US is quite a large locality.

Comment: I'm going to give the HIPAA questions some scrutiny before I spring the question, thanks for your advice!